# "No module named tensorflow" when tensorflow-gpu is required

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I built a python tensorflow package and uploaded to run on ml engine.

"tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0" (no tensorflow) is set to be required in my setup.py.

The ML engine run fails at "import tensorflow as tf" saying "No module named tensorflow".

The ML engine run works fine when I'm only requiring "tensorflow==1.8.0" but I believe tensorflow-gpu is needed to use GPU.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `--runtime-version=1.8` when submitting the job. Consequently, you don't need to manually specify TF in setup.py. In fact, if that's the only package you are requiring, you can omit setup.py altogether.

**Update 2018/06/29**:

Explanation: different versions of TensorFlow require different versions of NVIDIA's drivers and software stack. The `--runtime-version` is guaranteed to have the right version of the drivers for that particular version of TensorFlow. You can technically set the version of `tensorflow-gpu` in your setup.py, but that version must be compatible with the NVIDIA stack present in the `--runtime-version` you've selected (defaults to the very old TF 1.0).

Comment: To add to that: under the [`--runtime-version`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training) flag you'll find [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training) link to the list of runtime versions, where you can see that 1.8 supports tensorflow 1.8.0 for GPUs (although **not** for online prediction). To use GPUs in ML Engine, you only need to chose the correct values for `-scale-tier`, `--config` and `--region` as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus#requesting_gpu-enabled_machines).

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when you have multiple python versions. In that case you have to specify the relevant python version for tf installation. For example,"python3 setup.py" instead of "python setup.py".